# Can you change file name using php?

Tags: php, file-rename

So here's the idea.
Can you change/rename the name of the file using php.I was thinkig like this

you have couple of pages all same "template" just different content and name for example you have some file named "portfolio-item-1.php"
and if someone click "next" link it goes to "portfolio-item-2.php" so the same file just renamed and different content using ID's ?

It's maybe confusing but .. .

I know you can do this Database but, is there a way without database?

Comment: Yes you can, but can you be more specific why you want to do that? You can supplement ID using either GET or POST request.

Comment: URL rewriting and you dont even have to create gazillion files http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: what for make x files for the same content? it looks like plain html... not php

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to do that!  From what you say you're trying to do, a GET / POST would be far better.

E.g.  link to `portfolio-item.php?page=2`
You can get the page number by:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
```

This will set page to the ID in the URL if it's there, otherwise it'll use 1 as the page number.

Comment: but what if the first name is "some-title" and the other one is like "some-different-title-here" will it work then ?

Comment: What purpose do the files serve?  If you -really- want to work with specific files, you can pass in the filename as the page instead of a number if you wish.  You can then obtain the page name the same way, and do whatever you wish with the files, e.g. readfile()

Answer (score 0):

psynnott has the best method you would want to implement.
you can use a namespace instead of an integer but the same applies.